# how to insert input type date to mysql using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, materialize

I am facing problem updating my sql table. I am using materializecss and because of that i had to use

```
 <div class="input-field col l6 s12 m6">
                                    <input type="date" id="DOB" class="datepicker"/>
                                    <label for="DOBLBL">DATE OF BIRTH</label>
                                </div>
```

jquery for it:
 `$('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });`

C#

```
 string dob = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["DOB"]);
            string jd = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["JD"]);
            String userName = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("userDetails", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("nickName", nickNameTB.Text);
            MySqlParameter p2 = new MySqlParameter("dob", dob);
            MySqlParameter p3 = new MySqlParameter("joinDt", jd);
            MySqlParameter p4 = new MySqlParameter("memType", memTtype);
            MySqlParameter p5 = new MySqlParameter("usrname", userName);

            com.Parameters.Add(p1);
            com.Parameters.Add(p2);
            com.Parameters.Add(p3);
            com.Parameters.Add(p4);
            com.Parameters.Add(p5);

            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Routine which I created

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `userDetails`(IN `nickName` VARCHAR(15), IN `dob` DATE, IN `joinDt` DATE, IN `memType` INT(3), IN `usrname` VARCHAR(15))
NO SQL
update ozi_members
SET memberNickName = nickName,
memberDob = dob,
memberJoinDate = joinDt,
memberType = memType
WHERE memberUsername = usrname
```

I tried procedure and it works fine. So I think the  problem is with date format which I am taking from datepicker. please help.

Comment: What is the type of the field _memberDob_ ? as well the type of the field _memberjoinDate_

Comment: @Steve its date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fields are of type Date then you should pass a parameter of type Date.
If you pass a string then it is the database engine that needs to convert it to the date required by the field. A date is not a string and there is always a conversion at work here. This conversion could work or not, but why let this happen? Just create parameters specifying the type and pass a parameter value of the correct type

```
DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["DOB"]);
DateTime jd = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["JD"]);
....
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
using(MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("userDetails", con))
{
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("nickName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nickNameTB.Text;
    MySqlParameter p2 = new MySqlParameter("dob", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dob;
    MySqlParameter p3 = new MySqlParameter("joinDt", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = jd;
    ....
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note also the a connection and a command should be enclosed in a using statement to have a proper disposing of these objects and avoid resource leaks.

(The initial Convert.ToDateTime assumes that your Request.Form variables are in a correct format for a Date probably validated at client side. If not then you should use DateTime.TryParse and give an appropriate message if the input cannot be converted to a DateTime variable)

Comment: it worked and data updated in table. Thanks a lot. but I inserted today's date but it is showing 0001-01-01. Can you help me on that??

Comment: Not clear about the today date code. You can try to add the @ prefix to both the parameters in C# code and in the stored procedure.

Comment: I tried to add @ prefix but as i am using routine to create stored pro it is not giving results with @. it works only without @. And I whatever date i pick, it takes 0001-01-01 as input in database.

Comment: OK, let's forget the @ prefix. Can you add the code that pass the today date? And gives the 0001-01-01 value? By the way this is the MinValue of a datetime variable. This value is the default when a datetime variable is not initialized

Comment: I am using the same code. By today's date, I meant that I selected today's date in datepicker provided by the materialized css.

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure, **DO NOT** enclose the parameters in single quotes since it will not be treated like a parameter but as a value. Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `userDetails`(IN @nickName VARCHAR(15), 
IN @dob DATE, IN @joinDt DATE, IN @memType INT(3), IN @usrname VARCHAR(15))
# rest of code
```

Then from the application side make these changes to C# code:

```
MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("@nickName", nickNameTB.Text);
// Other parameters
```

Comment: I think those are backticks, no single quotes. Backticks are allowed in MySql as the square brackets in Sql Server. Good point about the @ prefix albeit I am not sure if it makes any difference

Comment: @Steve will it make any difference? Is my stored pro safe from sql injection?